# Firebase Database crashes Android app

Tags: android, database, firebase

Currently I am using the Firebase Storage service, and I am trying to add the Firebase Database service as well. However,

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

just crashes my app. (App has stopped working)

When I comment this line of code out, my app works perfectly fine. I have downloaded the google json file again, but I am still having the same problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error in your logcat?

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want to use Firebase Database:

```
DatabaseReference myDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem. You have to have the same version number when compiling different firebase services.